# Serializing an XDocument

Tags: c#, linq, serialization, linq-to-xml

I am trying to quickly and correctly serialize an `XDocument` object. I have tried several things, but this last one (found it [here](http://www.java2s.com/Book/CSharp/0100__LINQ-XML/Serialize_an_XDocument.htm)) seems simple and straightforward:

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
XmlWriterSettings sett = new XmlWriterSettings();
sett.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(b, sett);
doc.Save(xw);
String r = b.ToString();
```

However, at the end, `r` is just an empty string. Am I missing something? Why is it so hard to correctly serialize an `XDocument` object?

The frustrating thing is that if I call `doc.ToString()` I get a nice serialized XML string, without declaration. If I call `doc.ToString(true)` I get an empty string (`doc.Declaration` is set).

Comment: `xw.Close()` maybe? Although using a `using` statement would be better. That's what's actually missing from your code.

Comment: @AndreiV yes, that gives me results, but it completely ignores both the UTF8 setting and the `XDeclaration`, giving me (incorrect) UTF-16.

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening there with the encoding. Try to wrap it in a `using` statement.

Comment: Using `using` removes the need for `Close()`, but the encoding is still wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Still not convinced this is the "right" way to do it, but here goes:

```
MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream();
using (TextWriter b = new StreamWriter(s, Encoding.UTF8))
    doc.Save(b);

String r = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(s.ToArray());
```

This results in a correctly encoded and correctly declared XML string.